# Set PHP internet gateway

Tags: php

I know how to set a default **HTTP** proxy for functions like *fopen*, *file_get_contents* and *curl_exec*

```
putenv('http_proxy=http://ip:port')

stream_context_set_default(['http'=>['proxy'=>'tcp://ip:port']])
```

But is there a way to set a global gateway for all protocols not only HTTP like *ssh2_connect*, *mysqli_connect* inside PHP without OS routing? If not, how could I set a gateway just for one PHP script without afflicting the entire system (or with a minimal impact)?

Comment: Your question isnt clear, What type of gateway you are talking about?

Comment: Not **ip:port** for HTTP only but **ip** for ALL protocols. This is precisely my question. I don't know if the gateway feature exists in PHP.

Comment: Sounds like you need to configure your server's networking, not PHP.

Comment: I suspected it but I dreamed about an easy PHP hack.

Comment: which operating system is this on? it should be possible to run a process with a routing table of its own (including default gateway)

Comment: Ubuntu or Debian

Comment: @Joni pls tag me if/when you answer, you've piqued my interest.

Comment: @Sammitch on Linux you can create a separate network namespace and it'll have a routing table of its own. I can't write a well tested answer now but several people have blogged about this (for example https://blog.famzah.net/2014/06/05/private-networking-per-process-in-linux/ or https://blogs.igalia.com/dpino/2016/04/10/network-namespaces/)

Comment: @Joni it looks like it's intended for containerization, so I have to wonder if it might be easier to implement through docker config rather than poking around in the OS.